# Book about Shakespeare and Churchill as a robot

Tags: story-identification, robots, post-apocalyptic

I am looking for the name of a book; the details are as follows:

- It is set in London
- William Shakespeare and Winston Churchill are characters who turn out to be androids
- They are responsible for raising children to go out and repopulate the earth.

**What is the name of this book?**

Comment: Please give more information, e.g. Year it was published/when you read it...

Answer (score 7):

This is '[The Overman Culture](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1883512.The_Overman_Culture)' by Edmund Cooper.

Set in the far future, a group of children are raised by androids almost indistinguishable from humans except that they do not bleed.  Thus the children call them 'drybones'. 
Everyone has been given the name of someone famous from the past.
Churchill, Shakespeare, Queen Victoria and others make an appearance.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I have just noticed the OPs name... and mine...  :).

Comment: Awesome! I have been trying to recall this book for YEARS! Googled it multiple times, this is the first time I got a hit on 'drybones' :) Thanks!