# Science Fiction Book: historical characters are android teachers, girl pulls radio into bathtub

Tags: story-identification, books

I have the same question as was asked before:  William Shakespeare, Winston Churchill, Michael Faraday  and the like are all robots, androids, and are referred to in the book as "dry bones".  They are all used to teach children -- the goal being to repopulate the Earth
(after a war, a plague?)  There is also a "Library" -- somewhere in London (the setting.)

At one point, a girl in her bathtub calmly reaches up with her toe, and pulls the playing radio into the tub -- killing her (because the "world" is too weird???)

QUESTION:  Does anyone know the name of this book?

Comment: What question is this a dupe of?

Comment: Duplicating "Book about Shakespeare and Churchill as a robot"

Answer (score 2):

As per the answer to [the question this was previously marked as a duplicate to](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59647/book-about-shakespeare-and-churchill-as-a-robot?noredirect=1&lq=1), this may be *[The Overman Culture](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1883512.The_Overman_Culture)* by Edmund Cooper.

[image: Book Cover - The Overman Culture]

> "Michael had a good memory. He could remember things significant & insignificant. He remembered--if hazily--when he was young enough to be fed milk only. He remembered the odd child who disappeared from playschool & he remembered the other child who fell (or was pushed?) from the high window & lay all smashed & crumpled on the ground, but not bleeding & he remembered how he'd wanted to know about words, how you could keep them, how you could fix them--perhaps like a drawing--forever."
>
> "Time seems to have run amok. London is governed by Queen Victoria & Winston Churchill, populated by young people called 'fragiles' & others called 'drybones' because they don't bleed. The young fragiles come to realize that they're the last of their kind--whatever kind that might be.
>
> Thus is established the setting for a brilliant novel of adventure that speaks to the largest questions facing young people everywhere--questions of identity, of purpose in life & of responsibility for themselves & their kind."